# Kotlin FAB is still clickable after new fragment opens

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, floating-action-button

I have a layout that will open a new fragment via fab click. The problem I am running into is that the fab stays clickable when the new fragment is open. It is not visible, but if I click on the spot where it should be - it appears and does what it is programmed to do.

here is my code:
Activitymain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:clickable="true" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/fabHome" android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:focusable="true"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerMain"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="@string/no_lists_created_yet_press_the_icon"/>

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:id="@+id/fragmentHolder"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

mainActivity.kt

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.view.View
import com.internationalwoolly.shoppinglist.fragments.CreateNewList
import com.internationalwoolly.shoppinglist.recyclerview.RecyclerMainAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // controls if recycler view is shown
        if (RecyclerMainAdapter().isRecyclerViewEmpty()) {
            empty_view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            recyclerMain.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        recyclerMain.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerMain.adapter = RecyclerMainAdapter()
        //ends controls if recycler view is shown

        //controls the fab on the main page
        fabHome.setOnClickListener {
            val fragment = CreateNewList()
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragment).addToBackStack("back_profile_fragment").commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider posting the full code. Looks like that code snippet above has been shortened.

Comment: @Edric that's all the code except the recycler view adapter stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding a clickable and focus-able to the fragment xml